# Recursively mapping mines on a minesweeper board

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, minesweeper

I have been trying to make a minesweeper game where given coordinates for a cell it will recursively reveal adjacent cells until a cell adjacent to a bomb is found. I have a method that given coordinates x and y calculates how many mines are surrounding it.

```
// Counts how many mines are adjacent to a given coordinate cell if any
void board::mineCount(int x, int y) {

// North
if (y > 0) {
    if (board[x][y - 1].hasMine) {
        board[x][y].mineCount++;
    }
}

// South
if (y < dimensions[1] - 1) {
    if (board[x][y + 1].hasMine) {
        board[x][y].mineCount++;

    }
}

// East
if (x < dimensions[0] - 1) {
    if (board[x + 1][y].hasMine) {
        board[x][y].mineCount++;

    }
}

// West
if (x > 0) {
    if (board[x - 1][y].hasMine) {
        board[x][y].mineCount++;
    }
}

// North East
if (x < dimensions[0] - 1 && y > 0) {
    if (board[x + 1][y - 1].hasMine) {
        board[x][y].mineCount++;

    }
 }

// North West
if (x > 0 && y > 0) {
    if (board[x - 1][y - 1].hasMine) {
        board[x][y].mineCount++;
    }
}

// South East
if (x < dimensions[0] - 1 && y < dimensions[1] - 1) {
    if (board[x + 1][y + 1].hasMine) {
        board[x][y].mineCount++;

    }
}

// South West
if (x > 0 && y < dimensions[1] - 1) {
    if (board[x - 1][y + 1].hasMine) {
        board[x][y].mineCount++;
    }
  }
}
```

Each cell is a struct which has a `mineCount` field that gets incremented by 1 each time a mine is found adjacent to it. I am having trouble figuring out where my recursion logic would go. I tried doing something like:

```
// North
if (y > 0) {
    if (board[x][y - 1].hasMine) {
        board[x][y].mineCount++;
    } else {
        minecount(x, y-1);
    }
}
```

for each position but to no avail. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: What was the behavior of the recursion you tried and what was wrong about it?

Comment: Unrelated: Save yourself a lot of effort and compute the minecount for each grid coordinate once at start. It should let you chop this logic down dramatically and make it easier for you to spot your bug/solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recursion shouldn't be a part of the code that performs the mine count itself. It should be part of the function that's responsible for revealing nearby tiles.

```
int get_adjacent_mine_count(point p) {
    int mine_count = 0;
    for(int i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
        for(int j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
            point this_point(p.x + i, p.y + j);
            //is_inside_board checks to see if the point's coordinates are less than 0 
            //or greater than the board size
            if(!is_inside_board(board, this_point)) continue; 
            //We ignore the center tile
            if(i == 0 && j == 0) continue;

            if(board(this_point).hasMine) 
                mine_count++;
        }
    }
    return mine_count;
}

void reveal_tiles(point p) {
    //We shouldn't throw if the recursion is correct
    if(board(p).hasMine) throw Explosion("Stepped on a Mine!");
    //Single call to previously defined function
    int num_of_adjacent_mines = get_adjacent_mine_count(p);
    //I'm assuming this gets initialized to -1 beforehand
    board(p).revealed = num_of_adjacent_mines; 
    if(num_of_adjacent_mines == 0) {
        for(int i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
            for(int j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
                point this_point(p.x + i, p.y + j);
                if(!is_inside_board(board, this_point)) continue;
                if(i == 0 && j == 0) continue;
                if(board(this_point).revealed == -1) 
                    reveal_tiles(this_point);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm going to strongly recommend you write a simple `Matrix` class to represent `board`, which my code implies you've done, because that's a much more robust solution than just trying to interact with a 2D array the C-style way you're doing it.